# how to open HTML based games in python using PyQt5.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

i have few web based games on html and java-script , want to open it inside pyqt5 window in python.

i was trying it on tkinter but failed to render html in it.

need help

Thanks.
[Suppose this game (contra) want to play it inside pyqt5 window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FavLU.png)

[screenshot of pycharm package installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWMsl.png)

[Screenshots of IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MY5B.png)

[Screenshot pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRLHF.png)

Comment: Actually I've tried in my College Days but didn't find out any help, you need to rewrite the whole code in Python that's the only solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't using PyQt5 but you could launch a temp web server using SimpleHTTPServer

```
$ python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

or

```
$ python3 -m http.server 8000
```

It will serve up whatever is in the folder you run the command in. This shouldn't be used for production as it only provides the most basic security checks.

https://www.poftut.com/how-to-run-and-use-simple-http-server-in-python2-and-python3/

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use QWebEngineView that comes in the [PyQtWebEngine](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtwebengine/download) package

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    url = "https://www.retrogames.cz/play_022-NES.php?language=EN"
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebEngineWidgets'

Comment: @Akash You have to install it with the command: `pip3 install PyQtWebEngine`

Comment: have a script file and running it in pycharm community .

Comment: i m sure . i have checked the list of the packages its their  pyqt5 , PyQtWebEngine, pyqt-sip

Comment: Hi eyllanesc .. can i get your email or whatsapp so that i can chat with you regarding this.

Comment: i m new to pyqt , wanted to know if i can do such work in pyqt or not .

Comment: i m updating the question panel with the screenshot of my installed packages in pycharm. you can see their.

Comment: @Akash can you show me the error together and the code that you are using as an image

Comment: @Akash Why do not you run it in pycharm? Maybe IDLE is using a different python than Pycharm uses

Comment: result is the same with the pycharm as project interpreter is the same.

Comment: @Akash I have asked for an image, if you want help, please provide it and if not then goodbye.

Comment: u can see image in the 4th link

Comment: @Akash I find it very strange that where you installed python is in `C:\Users\dhram\PyCharmProject\pyqt` but the python that is displayed in the console is in another path.

Comment: C:\Users\dhram\PyCharmProject\pyqt  (project path )

Comment: @Akash Check the console in the last image you have shown, it says `/path/of/python.exe /path/of/.py`

Answer (score 0):

You could load the page in a `QWebView`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView as QWebView, QWebEnginePage as QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("https://oldgameshelf.com/contra-208.html"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you need to scroll to a particular element, you could pass JavaScript to `web.runJavaScript()` that does the scrolling.

In the example above, I used the oldgameshelf.com link of the game you linked to. But you could replace this with the URL of any page.

Also, make sure you install PyQtWebEngine if you haven't already:

`pip install PyQtWebEngine`

Since it's now in a separate package.